# How do I get rid of repeating special characters with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I want to get rid of all the repetitive dots except the ones that were one dot.

Sources:

```
(1) "a... b."
(2) "a....... b... c."
```

Results I want:

```
(1) "a b."
(2) "a b c."
```

Code:

```
import re

a = "a... b."
b = "a....... b... c."

result = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\.{1}]", "", a)
print(result)

result = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\.{1}]", "", b)
print(result)

result = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ][\\.{2,}]", "", a)
print(result)

result = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ][\\.{2,}]", "", b)
print(result)
```

Doesn't work.

How can I do to get my results?

Comment: Try `r'\.{2,}|[^a-zA-Z0-9.\s]'`, see https://regex101.com/r/EbiuMk/1

Comment: match 2 or more dots? `"\.{2,}"` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488557/remove-consecutive-dotsperiods-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code can do the needed task

```
import re
result = re.sub("\\.{2,}","","a....b....c.d....e.")
print(result)
```

Result will be-
**abc.de.**

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import re
    
a = "a... b."
b = "a....... b... c."
    
result = re.sub("\\.{2,}","", a)
print(result)
    
result = re.sub("\\.{2,}","", b)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\.{2,}|[^a-zA-Z0-9.\s]', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EbiuMk/1).

*Details*:

- `\.{2,}` - two or more dots
- `|` - or
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9.\s]` - any char other than an ASCII letter, digit, any whitespace or `.` chars.